# Is there a way to get PhpStorm/WebStorm to use a custom domain in previews?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

Without any configuration, the default action when clicking on a browser icon in PhpStorm/WebStorm is to open the file in `localhost:port`.

Is there a way to get PhpStorm to use a custom domain? (Let's assume the domain is already setup to point to `127.0.0.1` in your `/etc/hosts` file.)

[image: Launch Preview Button]
[image: Localhost with port in address bar]

Answer (score 4):

You may want to configure deployment (Build, Execution, Deployment | Deployment) and specify "Web Server URL" there. In this case, "Open in browser" action will refer to this setting instead of built-in server.

More about deployment:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/settings-deployment.html

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just define deployment entry and mark it as Default for this project. It will now be used instead of PhpStorm's built-in simple webserver.

`Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Deployment`

URL from `Web server root URL` field will be used instead of `localhost:63342`.